# Creating lambda predicate in run-time dynamically based on <T> type

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, func

I have a `ListForm<T>` form in my windows application project.
also i defined `predicate` field as `Func<Order,bool>` in that form

```
private Func<T,bool> predicate;
```

my `ListForm` may create with diffrent types such as `OrderDTO`, `CustomerDTO`, `DocumentDTO`,...

```
public class OrderDTO
{
   public string Number {get; set;}
   public string CustomerName {get; set;}
   public int Weight {get; set;}
}

public class CustomerDTO
{
   public int CustomerId {get; set;}
   public string CustomerName {get; set;}
}
```

is there any way that i build `predicate` in run-time dynamically with all properties of `<T>` type?(assume that always strings must compare with `"X"` and integers with `0`) for example if `ListForm` created with `OrderDTO` type `predicate` should be :

```
t=>t.Number == "X" && t.CustomerName == "X" && t.Weight == 0;
```

and if it create with `CustomerDTO` type, the predicate should be

```
t=> t.CustomerId == 0 && t.CustomerName == "X";
```

i want use it for creating a dynamic search form.

in fact i have a filter selection window that user can define his filter conditions to datas in `ListForm`,and this filter window creates dynamically as i described in [Creating a generic search form based on ISearchable types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17135238/1594487)

Comment: What are your end goal with this? It seems like you might be overcomplicating the problem...

Comment: You can also use `Predicate<T>` instead of `Func<T,bool>`. More intuitive.

Comment: @Steven: could you please explain more?

Comment: Are you planning to pass these predicates into an Entity Framework search?

Comment: @Masoud: This is not an answer to your question, but instead of using `System.Func<T, TResult>` with `TResult` being a `bool`, you can use `System.Predicate<T>` instead, since the signature is equal to `Func<T, bool>` but it has a name that is more descriptive for its purpose, since it is named `Predicate`, and this is what you want: a predicate. This is more readable and more intuitive.

Comment: @Masoud do you really need all those dynamic stuff? If I correctly understand your question - you can solve it with creating some predicates at compile time

Comment: @ig-melnyk: How can I define the predicates at compile time?

Comment: @Masoud create predicate for each type of collection and when user wants to make a query on certain fields of collection - just "ignore" them : Predicate<Order> predOrder = o=>(o.orderID==orderID || selectedID) && .. where selectedID is true if user checked this field

Answer (score 0):

Build your predicate as below:

```
private void BuildPredicate()
    {
        predicate = (obj) =>
        {
            var t = typeof(T);
            var strProps = t.GetProperties().Count(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string) && p.GetValue(obj, null) != "X");
            var intProps = t.GetProperties().Count(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(int) && (int)p.GetValue(obj, null) != 0);
            if (strProps == 0 && intProps == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        };
    }
```